# Looking for the recurrence relation for certain trigonometric integrals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, recurrence-relations

By assuming that:
$$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^4(x)}{\sin^5(x)}\,dx = k,$$
what does the integral $$ \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^6(x)}{\sin^7(x)}\,dx$$ equal in terms of k?

I have manipulated both integrals to get $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} (\csc^2(x)-1)^2(\csc(x))\,dx$ and $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\csc^2(x)-1)^3(\csc(x))\,dx$.
I'm not sure where to go from here.

I multiplied $(\csc^2(x)-1)^2$ and $(\csc^2(x)-1)^3$ out, but I still couldn't find a solution.

Please help!

Comment: Is there a typo? The integrals do not exist. If we allow $k=\infty$, then the second integral is $k$.

Comment: Oh! Oops, the integrals should all be cosx over sinx, not the other way around. Sorry!

Comment: The second integrand is $\int \cot^5 x \cot x\csc x$. Integrate by parts, letting $u=\cot^5 x$ and $dv=\cot x\csc x\,dx$. You will wind up still needing to integrate something like $5\cot^4 x\csc^3 x$. Write $\csc^2 x$ as $\cot^2 x+1$. Continue.

Comment: $$I_1=-\frac{\sqrt2+3\ln\tan\frac\pi8}{8}\qquad\qquad;\qquad\qquad I_2=\frac{13\sqrt2+15\ln\tan\frac\pi8}{48}$$

Comment: Okay! Thank-you! With these problems, I know what I'm looking for just not so much how to find it haha. So in general, to find the equivalent of the first integral, its best to integrate the second one by parts and then manipulate the integral vdu? Or is it also possible that in problems like this you will need to perform another integration by parts? Or in other words, how do you know when you've done enough and you should start looking for similarities?

Answer (score 1):

By setting
$$ I_n = \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^{2n}x}{\sin^{2n+1}x}dx$$
we have

> $$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{2n}}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}du.\tag{1}$$

This follows from the variable changes $x=\arcsin t, t=\sqrt{s}, s=1/r, r=u+1$, or just $x=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u}}\right)$, for short.
Since:
$$\frac{d}{du}\operatorname{arcsinh} u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}},\qquad \frac{d}{du}\sqrt{1+u^2}=\frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}},$$
integration by parts gives that $I_n$ is always a linear combination of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)=-\log\tan\frac{\pi}{8}=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$ with rational coefficients. In facts:
$$I_n + I_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{1}u^{2n}\sqrt{1+u^2}du=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\cdot I_{n+1},$$
or:
$$I_{n+1} = \frac{\sqrt{2}-(2n+1)\cdot I_n}{2n+2},$$

> $$ (2n+1)\cdot  I_n + (2n+2)\cdot I_{n+1} = \sqrt{2},$$
> $$ I_0 = \log(1+\sqrt{2}).\tag{2}$$

We can also write $I_n$ as a value of the incomplete [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$I_n = \frac{1}{2}\cdot B\left(\frac{1}{2},n+\frac{1}{2},-n\right),$$
or recover $I_n$ from the coefficients of a Taylor series, since $(1)$ gives:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}I_n\, x^{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right).\tag{3}$$

Exploiting convexity we have:
$$I_n\geq \int_{1-\frac{2}{4n-1}}^{1}\frac{(4n-1)u-(4n-3)}{2\sqrt{2}}\,du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}(4n-1)}>\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\,n},$$
and by plugging this inequality into $(2)$ we get:
$$ I_n < \frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}\,n}.$$
Since $I_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n+1}-\frac{I_{n+1}}{2n+1}$, we get the asymptotic:

> $$ I_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}\,n}+\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).\tag{4}$$

Integration by parts gives other terms of the asymptotics, in virtue of:
$$I_n -\frac{1}{(2n+1)\sqrt{2}}= \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{u^{2n}}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}-\frac{u^{2n}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)du=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{2n}\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)}{(1-u^2)\sqrt{2(1+u^2)}}\,du.$$